# Can you use breakpoints in extension tests?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When writing integration tests for a VSCode extension, are you able to use breakpoints?

I am running the tests in the default hello-world example from the yeoman generator. My breakpoints are not being hit. I had a guess and set stopOnEntry to true in launch.json, however it didn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work, if not I suggest you file an issue over at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: I can confirm that as of now (4/2/2016) it does work. I just tested it and it stops at the breakpoint in the test.